# WPF. Замена лэйутов.

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Есть пользовательский контрол такого типа.
[image]
Мне нужно будет после определенного действия  заменить все это на однотонный рисунок, желательно бы, чтобы все эти леауты сменились одним. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Миллионы возможных способов.

Например, так:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Однотонный" Visibility="Hidden" Background="Orange"/>
        <DockPanel x:Name="Леауты" Visibility="Visible">
             <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Control Grid.Column="0"/>
                 <Control Grid.Column="1"/>
             </Grid>
             ...
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Вы можете переключать `Visibility` в code-behind или забиндить на подходящее свойство VM через `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Comment: Мне нужно будет все это заменить на 1 лейаут, тут немного не то, если я правильно понял, но тоже полезные вещи. А что если, у меня будет Grid, который я буду делать невидимым и шириной равной 0, там как раз и будет мое второе изображение. И когда будет нужно буду его разворачивать? Попахивает парком велосипедов, но все же)

Comment: @alex91: ну, поместите то, на что надо заменить, в "однотонный" `Grid`. Шириной 0 делать я бы не советовал, просто скажите Visibility="Hidden" или даже лучше "Collapsed".